# Accurately selecting a node based on path from SKShapeNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, cgpath

I'm working on determining which node is tapped in an SKScene. I have a line that is created from a `CGMutablePath` and added to an `SKShapeNode`.  However, when trying to accurately select this line, it is included in the array returned from `nodesAtPoint` whenever i tap anywhere within it's accumulated rectangle frame. See the image for more detail. I'm able to tap anywhere within those blue or red squares and still get the line from `nodesAtPoint`. I'm trying to figure out a way to only return the node from `nodesAtPoint` if the actual path was tapped (or maybe a threshold of +- 20 points to help). What method am i looking for?

[image]

Here is some relevant code that i've tried based on some articles i've found.

```
let tempActualTouchedNodes = self.nodes(at: positionInScene)
for n in tempActualTouchedNodes {
  if let tempLine = n as? LineNode {
     if tempLine.contains(touch.location(in: tempLine)){
       print("yes")
     }
  }
}
```

However, "yes" is never printed.

Comment: Yes never prints because you can't guarantee that the touch location is in the tempLine,  E.G. your tempLine consist of points 0,0 and 0,1.  my touch is 0.0,0.5.  The touch is on the line, but on on your points.  You need a new way to solve your problem

Comment: @Knight0fDragon can you please rephrase?  What do you mean "the touch is on the line, but on on your points"?  I've tried various other ways to solve this to no avail, but i feel like there should be a built-in method or easy way of detecting a touch on a path. No?

Comment: Why do i need to rephrase, I gave you an example, if you do not understand the concept of a line then no amount of rephrasing is going to help you.  I will change one thing, on on means not on*

Comment: @Knight0fDragon So you're saying, the "points" as in each end of the the line is where it would detect the touch?  Everything in between is not considered part of it?

Comment: According to the documentation for 'nodesAtPoint', that should include any CGPath created and part of an SKShapeNode.

Comment: nodesAtPoint are  going to return nodes that are in the frame, your problem is not your for loop, you are probably going inside of it, your problem is your if statements,  comment them out and you will see "yes" printed twice

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Well of course that would, i already know that. That's the problem. `nodesAtPoint` is returning the line (or both) when i tap _anywhere_ in those red or blue rectangles. Not just _on_ the line

Comment: yes, it is suppose to, that is what nodesAtPoint does.  it is a simple point in rect check for efficiency purposes.  You need to find a way to better evaluate the touch after.  `contains` will not get you there.  You need to check if you are on the line with a formula,  check this page out http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65721.html to learn more